# iOS HERE SDK NMAKit private API usage

Tags: ios, here-api

I just updated my app to the latest 3.13.2 HERE SDK version but once I uploaded a build to the App Store I got the following warning:

```
The app references non-public symbols in Frameworks/NMAKit.framework/NMAKit: _getcontext, _makecontext, _setcontext
```

I haven't tried submitting a build with this warning actually to App Review but this warning doesn't bode well and even if it did make it through would most likely increase the review time for my app significantly. My app relies on the HERE SDK for its navigation features so as such I can't just remove it completely. For now I've rolled back to a previous version which doesn't give this warning for uploaded builds.

Comment: Sorry but what question are you asking? If it's about whether this problem will cause issues with your App Review or that Apple won't approve it it might be best suited for you to try and contact them with the issue and seeing what their response is.

Comment: @AlanS He's indirectly asking why the HERE SDK (3.13.2) is suddenly referencing non-public symbols. It's more of a notice to the developers that this latest version isn't working for App Store submissions. I faced the same issue with my submission being rejected.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the issue, we have reported the bug to the developer. Is it a IOS Starter SDK or Premium IOS SDK

Comment: Yeah I couldn't find any references to this online so that's why I decided to make it a public SO question (this also seems to be the only way to raise issues from the HERE support pages).

And I'm using the premium iOS SDK

Comment: Looking.
You can also raise a ticket on [Github](https://github.com/heremaps/here-ios-sdk-examples/issues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 3.13.2 HERE SDK, openssl library was upgraded to 1.1.1c version which causes [such error](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/2545).

In order to fix it, openssl configuration needs to be changed. It is planned to be implemented in next HERE SDK(3.14) release.

Since it is just warning you can still try submitting your app.
Thanks for reporting!

UPDATE:

[Warnings](https://prnt.sc/pgii84) have been fixed in 3.13.3, which is available now.

Comment: I have tried to upload my project with updated v3.13 HERE Maps and my build got rejected and deleted with the same error. So, it is not only a warning, this issue rejects the build. Can you tell estimated time when we can expect sdk update?
https://prnt.sc/pgii84

Comment: The suggested fix is done. It was planned to be released in 3 months in 3.14 version. However, if it is not just a warning then I guess we will release it in 1 month in 3.13.3. The problem is I can not reproduce the issue. Can you list the NMA classes or API you use in your app which might cause such error? 
i.e. When I use navigationState of NMANavigationManager, I get the similar warning of private API usage(_navigationState). Which is strange. Even though it is public, we just use readwrite for it in NMANavigationManager private category.

Comment: I was able to reproduce it by simply running $nm libcrypto.a | grep context. But not $nm NMAKit. Indeed, the root cause is in upgrading openssl lib to 1.1.1c.

Comment: @dashchak I faced the same issue and I am unable to update build on testflight because of this issue. Can you tell me exact date for the update. Thanks.

Comment: It was agreed to provide the fix in 3.13.3 and release it by the end of next week.

Comment: @dashchak thank you for the reply. Is there is any round about way to submit app to testflight or I have to wait till next week ?

Comment: Due to another urgent fix, 3.13.3 release date is shifted. We expect it to appear on dev portal as well as on CocoaPods on Monday. Sorry for inconvenience. 
There is no workarounds I am aware of. For me issue is only reproduced when I use CocoaPods. When I manually embed NMAKit, warnings are not generated.

Comment: @Leena you can use 3.12.2 version of here maps sdk and if you are having crashes on iOS 13 you can set `Metal API Validation` to `false` in scheme options tab. This way I successfully uploaded my build to TF and only got a warning of deprecated UIWebView usage.

Comment: 3.13.3 is now available in CocoaPods: https://cocoapods.org/pods/HereMaps and on https://developer.here.com/. 
Let me know if any warning still exist.

Comment: @dashchak thank you for the update I update my pods and try to upload app on testflight.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem as you with v3.13.2. Meanwhile, my workaround is to use and older version: 3.12.2 and it works. So, just add this in the pod file:

```
pod 'HEREMaps', '3.12.2'
```

Hope it helps!